# Mapping result of a native SQL query to Grails domain class

Tags: hibernate, grails

Is it possible to map the result of a native SQL query to a collection of Grails domain class instances?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
import com.acme.domain.*

def sessionFactory
sessionFactory = ctx.sessionFactory  // this only necessary if your are working with the Grails console/shell
def session = sessionFactory.currentSession 

def query = session.createSQLQuery("select f.* from Foo where f.id = :filter)) order by f.name");
query.addEntity(com.acme.domain.Foo.class); // this defines the result type of the query
query.setInteger("filter", 88);
query.list()*.name;
```

Comment: What was missing for me in this answer is that `def sessionFactory` must appear in the control (if you're doing this in a controller like I am).  The field is injected and then you can do sessionFactory.currentSession.

Comment: after 2 hours i get a lots of "o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 53300
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : FATAL: remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections"
when i use this implementation and i already have max connections set to -1. is it possible to close a hibernate connection with your imlementation?

Answer (score 8):

Alternatively using Groovy SQL in the Grails app

```
import  groovy.sql.Sql

class TestQService{

    def dataSource  //Auto Injected

    def getBanksForId(int bankid){

        def sql = Sql.newInstance(dataSource)

        def rows = sql.rows(""" Select BnkCode , BnkName from Bank where BnkId = ?""" , [bankid]) 

        rows.collect{
            new Bank(it)
        }

    }


    class Bank{

        String BnkCode
        String BnkName

        }

}
```

Comment: Sql.newInstance(dataSource) fails as there is no method that takes a datasourc object.

Answer (score 2):

You could map it yourself without too much trouble. Alternatively if using HQL, you could use `select new map()` and then take `query.list().collect { new MyDomainObject(it) }` to bind the parameters by hand.

Comment: True but I'd suppose this would be significantly slower than Hibernate's heavily optimized code.