# Grails domain object with select query

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a requirement where in I need to get some 10 different colums from 5 different tables of oracle. Basically I want to execute a custom select query and I want to understand from you guys whether I can create a custom domain object and get data populated in this domain object using grails. Some thoughts some links where I can explore more, it would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need a domain class? You can use plain Groovy SQL to execute any query you want. Using a domain class seems overkill here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use straight Groovy SQL with the `dataSource` bean.  This is an example from an integration test.

```
def dataSource

@Test
public void sql() {
    Sql sql = new Sql(dataSource)
    List<GroovyRowResult> results = sql.rows("select * from user")
    println results[0].first_name
    println results[0].<COLUMN_NAME>
}
```

Whatever raw SQL you need to use can be put inside of the call to `sql.rows()` and the result is a List of `GroovyRowResult` which can essentially be treated like a Map

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like suggested here:
[Mapping result of a native SQL query to Grails domain class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088641/mapping-result-of-a-native-sql-query-to-grails-domain-class)

```
import com.acme.domain.*

def sessionFactory
sessionFactory = ctx.sessionFactory  // this only necessary if your are working with the Grails console/shell
def session = sessionFactory.currentSession 

def query = session.createSQLQuery("select f.* from Foo where f.id = :filter)) order by f.name");
query.addEntity(com.acme.domain.Foo.class); // this defines the result type of the query
query.setInteger("filter", 88);
query.list()*.name;
```